# How to go back a page in React or JS and handle else

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

The 2 parts of this if/else statement work separately but not when put together. Any ideas on how to make it work? I want the user to click a button that allows them to not enter the website and if they came from a different page it will take them there, otherwise if they didn't come from a different page it will take them to Udemy. Thx

```
function goBack (){
    if (window.history.go(-1)){
      window.history.go(-1)
    }
     else {
      
      window.location.href="https://www.udemy.com/"
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: `window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: That works fine but I don't want there to be a situation where the user clicks and nothing happens so I might just have to use `window.location.href="https://udemy.com"`

Comment: looks like you'll never get inside the if statement because go method is  asynchronous.
your goBack should have only one responsibility to go back so if you pass -1 it'll go back and if no history it will reload the page. remove if and else statement

Comment: goBack() like this `function goBack (){     window.history.go(-1);    }` does work on desktop but if there is no previous page on iOS it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It seems like I would need to check if iOS is running using a navigator method which I am just discovering now.